# Script to gracefully kill X server and drop to tty?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, tty, session

I use the terminal to do the majority of my day-to-day computing, so I have the default runlevel set to `3` in `/etc/inittab` and I only start the X server when I need to. I currently have the following in my `xorg.conf` in order to make quickly switching to the terminal easier:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option            "DontZap"    "false"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier        "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard   "yes"
    Option            "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

I know this is messy and fraught with security problems, which is why these settings were removed from the default install in the first place. However, it's fast. How can I get this kind of functionality in a safer way using a shell script or something similar that can be attached to an event such as a key combination or to closing the screen of a laptop?

What I am after is an immediate killing of the X server process with no output to tty (currently, `Ctrl + Alt + Bksp` fills the terminal with the output from the dying X server, which I have to exit with `Ctrl + C`).

Comment: What about invoking it from a screen/tmux session and doing the killing there?

Comment: Or background it with `&`. Wouldn't that accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution That I Have Settled With

This issue still plagues me somewhat, but I have mashed together a multi-pronged solution that gets very close to what the original question was seeking, to the point that I am marking this issue "resolved".

### 1.) Remove the xorg.conf changes

These changes to `xorg.conf` from the OP can be removed, as the functionality will be replicated in another way:

```
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option            "DontZap"    "false"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    Identifier        "Keyboard Defaults"
    MatchIsKeyboard   "yes"
    Option            "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

### 2.) Edit .xinitrc

Most guides to using `.xinitrc` suggest adding a line such as this one to start your desktop of choice when Xorg starts:

```
exec cinnamon-session;
```

However, in an `.xinitrc` file, anything after an `exec` statement gets ignored. So alter it to just call the desktop without the `exec`:

```
cinnamon-session;
```

Then add a `clear` on the line below it, so that when the desktop session ends, it clears the screen:

```
cinnamon-session;
clear;
```

Because of the time taken to end the session, there may still be a couple of lines remaining from ending the session (and this is what I mean when I say this issue still plagues me somewhat; I haven't figured out how to solve this part completely).

### 3.) Create a shell script to end the session

I mentioned in step 1 that the Xorg zapping functionality will be replicated in another way, and that happens here. This particular example is unique to Cinnamon, but there may be a similar command for your desktop. Make a shell script with the following two lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cinnamon-session-quit --logout --force --no-prompt;
```

Make the script executable with `chmod +x quit-x.sh` (or whatever you've named it.) The reason I had to make a tiny shell script to pull this off is because I had issues mapping a key combination to a command with options, but mapping it to a script was a snap (see step 4).

### 4.) Map the script to a key combination

This is also highly desktop specific. The settings for this in Cinnamon are located in the System Settings application, under Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts. Click "Add custom shortcut", give it a name ("Quit X", for example), give it a shortcut (I chose `Alt-T`), and point it at your custom script. Now dropping to a terminal is a snap.